# Erro no device(Samsung Galaxy S4) ao executar app, porem no Emulador funciona!

Tags: android, emulador

Estou com um problema, fiz uma aplicação que consome um *webservice* RestFull feito em Visual Studio, quando executo a aplicação do Android Studio, consome sem problemas, porem quando uso no device(Galaxy S4) ou Tablet Samsung, ela não funciona e dá erro sempre na mesma linha.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Tentei usar o *logcat* pra ver o erro `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.25.115/wsBA.asmx/ConsultarLogin` na exceção.

O pior é que no emulador funciona, acessei o *webservice* de outro computador que tenho pra ver se era questão de permissão de acesso, porem passando os parâmetros via `GET` direto no *browser* do outro micro acessa.

Abaixo segue código da *Actvity* que está dando esse erro:

```
package br.com.intelider.bomapetiteandroid;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


/**
 * Created by gleyson on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class login_activity extends ActionBarActivity {
   EditText edLogin;
   EditText edSenha;
   Button btnLogar;
   TextView txtBemVindo;
   TextView txtNumUser;
   Integer userId;
   //LoginService loginService;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //retirando a barra do relogio
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //inicio
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);

        btnLogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogar);
        edLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLogin);
        edSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSenha);
        txtBemVindo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBemVindo);
        txtNumUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHost);


        final Button btnLogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogar);
        btnLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btLogar:
                        String txtUsr = edLogin.getText().toString();
                        String txtPwd = edSenha.getText().toString();
                        if (!txtUsr.equals("") && !txtPwd.equals("")) {
                            String restURL = "http://192.168.25.115/wsBA.asmx/ConsultarLogin";
                            new RestOperation().execute(restURL);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(login_activity.this, "Insira o usuário e senha!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
         });

        sqlite_configuracao con = new sqlite_configuracao(this);
        configuracao_class config = con.buscarTodosConfig();
        if (config != null) {
            TextView etHost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHost);
            etHost.setText(String.valueOf(config.getHost()));
        }
    }

    private class RestOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String content;
        String error;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(login_activity.this);
        String intLogin = "";
        String strSenha = "";
        TextView serverDataReceived = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverDataReceived);
        TextView showParsedJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showParsedJSON);
        EditText userinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLogin);
        EditText pawdinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSenha);



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setTitle("Por favor aguarde ...");
            progressDialog.show();

            try {
                intLogin += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("intLogin", "UTF-8") + "=" + userinput.getText();
                strSenha += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("strSenha", "UTF-8") + "=" + pawdinput.getText();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            BufferedReader br = null;

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                 OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStreamWr.write(intLogin + strSenha);
                outputStreamWr.flush();

    //******* Linha onde dá erro **********
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);
                String line = null;


                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }

                content = sb.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                error = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (error != null) {
                serverDataReceived.setText("Error " + error);
            } else {
                serverDataReceived.setText(content);

                String output = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject child = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String par_id = child.getString("PAR_ID_23");
                        String par_razao = child.getString("PAR_RAZAO_SOCIAL_23");
                        String par_senha = child.getString("PAR_SENHA_23");

                        output = "Name = " + par_id + System.getProperty("line.separator") + par_razao + System.getProperty("line.separator") + par_senha;
                        output += System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    }

                    showParsedJSON.setText(output);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_Configuracoes:
                CarregaTelaConfiguracao();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void CarregaTelaConfiguracao(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, configuracao_activity.class));
    }

  }
```

#### Edição

1) Sobre as permissões esta assim no androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

2)Esta conectado na mesma rede wireless que fica aqui na minha sala

3) Eu já tinha desabilitado firewall e antivírus, sobre o webservice eu acesso do meu notebook normalmente.

O Verifiquei outra coisa o exemplo que eu peguei pra fazer o meu funciona sem problema. Já o meu da erro só no device na linha:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Notei mais uma coisa: que a minha aplicação faz e o exemplo não faz, quando executa aparece a mensagem varias vezes no logcat:

> Skipped 300 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Esse número 300  varia.

Comment: oi @Felipe, debugando e pesquisando vi que o erro vem do getInputStream(), é uma excessão genérica do java.io, o que me incomoda é que ela só ocorra no device e não no emulador, estou lendo a documentação java para ver se encontro alguma solução. Coloquei a mesma versão 4.4.2, porem o erro ainda persiste da mesma maneira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual versão do Android do Emulador e a do Galaxy S4?
Parece que o problema começou a ocorrer em devices que utilizam Android 4 ou superior.

Faça um teste retirando o trecho:

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Isso deve ser utilizado apenas para chamadas POST.

Usei como fonte o seguinte post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365829/filenotfoundexception-for-httpurlconnection-in-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: Boa tarde, Debugando e pesquisando vi que o erro vem do getInputStream(), é uma excessão genérica do java.io, o que me incomoda é que ela só ocorra no device e não no emulador, estou lendo a documentação java para ver se encontro alguma solução. Coloquei a mesma versão 4.4.2, porem o erro ainda persiste da mesma maneira.

Comment: Consegui Felipe muito obrigado, o problema era realmente a que voce disse a linha connection.setDoOutput(true), porem não funcionava, dai pesquisando vi que tinha que explicitar que o metodo era POST dai acrescentei connection.setRequestMethod("POST") e funcionou, Valeu irmão!

Answer (score 3):

A primeira coisa que eu faria pra descobrir aonde está o problema é verificar as permissões do app, se está com permissão de acesso a internet.

A segunda seria verificar se o device está na mesma rede que o seu "servidor".

Uma outra coisa seria verificar se tem alguma porta bloqueada no seu servidor.